# Unable to SSH with Keypair

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, key-pair

I want to SSH with a new User to my EC2 Instance using Keypair.

**1. First I create a new user, a directory in the Home directory and create a new Keypair**

- sudo adduser Joe --disabled-password
- sudo su - Joe
- mkdir .ssh
- chmod 700 .ssh touch .ssh/authorized_keys
- chmod 600 .ssh/authorized_keys
- create keypair from the AWS console and saving it on Desktop

**2. Using my mac terminal, I am generating the public key**

- ssh-keygen -y
- copy & paste the public key into Vim
- vim authorised_keys
- pasting the public key in 1 line
- in vim using the command :w to paste
- in vim command :wq

**3. Done with all the set up.. Time to test it:**

$ ssh -i "keypair.pem" joe@xx.xxx.xxx.xxx

**ERROR**

$ joe@xx.xxx.xxx.xxx's password:

What am I doing wrong here - why is it asking me for a password if I have skipped that in the very first step?

If I entered a UNIX Password when creating a the new User, its working all fine  and I am able to connect.

I have followed these exact steps: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/new-user-accounts-linux-instance/

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Where exactly are you updating `.ssh/authorized_keys` from step 1? It seems to me its empty based on your description.

Comment: @Marcin before Step 1, I am connecting via SSH with main Root User, if its that what you mean?

Comment: Could it be `Joe` vs `joe`?